# Code will get only first lot of values from spinboxes on button push - does not update after then

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I have written some code that gets a number of attributes from a list if that list contains a value of one or more in a certain entry. The entry in this case is the Spinbox values that the user selects, called `model_quantity_list`. It works fine for the first time; when the user enters how many quantities of each item they want and pushes the button it will return those quantities along with all the details of the product they want.

However if the user then wants to change a value in one of the Spinboxes and then push the button again to return the values, they need to close the window and run the program again.

Below is a snippet of the code that is used to achieve this so far. Below that is the full code that is needed to run the program, just in case anyone wants to run it.

My question is, what do I put into my code so that it will refresh on each button click and get the new values?

*Please not, this is my first week coding. Please leave me some feedback if you would like to down-vote the question so I can work on improving how I write.*

## Snippet

```
watch_list = zip(watch_names, watch_image_urls, watch_prices, watch_link_urls, model_quantity_list, model_total_price)
watch_option = {'watch_{}'.format(i): e for i, e in enumerate(watch_list)}
    for number, each in enumerate(watch_option):
        if watch_option['watch_'+str(number)][4] >= 1:
            print watch_option['watch_'+str(number)]
```

## Entire program

```
from Tkinter import Tk, Button, Canvas, END, Spinbox, PhotoImage, Label
from ttk import Progressbar, Combobox
from urllib import urlopen
from re import findall
import urllib

## Create a window
window = Tk()

## Give the window a title
window.title('Watch finder')

## Show Dennisov image logo
dennisov_logo_url = "http://i.imgur.com/KD6AK08.gif"
handle = urlopen(dennisov_logo_url)
data = handle.read()
raw_image = PhotoImage(master = window, data = data)
Label(window, image = raw_image, width = 600).grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan = 10)
handle.close

## Types of Dennisov watches - INTRODUCE THE WATCH NAMES FUNCTION HERE AS THIS IS
## HARDCODED
dennisov_type_list = ['Barracuda Limited','Barracuda Chronograph',
                      'Barracuda Mechanical','Speedster','Free Rider',
                      'Nau Automatic','Lady Flower','Enigma','Number One']

## Open a new HTML file enable writing to it
dennisov_file = open('dennisov_url.html', 'w')

## Begin writing to HTML file
dennisov_file.write('''
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Watches</title>
    </head>
    <body>
''')  

dennisov_file.write('''
</body>
</html>
''')

## Define function for selection button push
def show_models():
## Make function read from user dropdown box selection
    dennisov_type_selection = (dennisov_dropdown_box.get())
## Convert to lower-case and replaces spaces with "_" to be used in URL
    dennisov_type = dennisov_type_selection.lower().replace(' ','_')
## Complete the Dennisov URL using the converted user name selection
    dennisov_url = 'https://denissov.ru/en/'+ dennisov_type + '/'
## Make a varibale for the Dennisov subpage from the URL domain onwards
    dennisov_url_subpage = dennisov_url[19:]

## Read the Dennisov URL HTML
    dennisov_html = urlopen(dennisov_url).read()
## Replace instances of double quotation marks in the text with singles 
## so that the findall regex code does not get confused 
    dennisov_html = dennisov_html.replace('"', "'")

## Find all of the images of the watches. Each watch image starts with the text
## "img src=". Do not match those with any " symbols in the URL
    global watch_image_urls
    watch_image_urls = findall("<img src='(/files/collections/o[^']*)'", dennisov_html)
## Add the URL domain to each watch image subpage to create full addresses
    watch_image_urls = ['https://denissov.ru' + remainder for remainder in watch_image_urls]
##    dennisov_file.write('        <img src="' + image + '">\n')
## Download and save the PNG images to the directory as GIFs so that
## Tkinter can use them

## Return the watch 'type'. The watch type is in a title tag called "titlusref"
## and can be any combination of letters and spaces, followed by a space and
## "<" symbol. 
    global watch_type
    watch_type = findall("titlusref'\>([a-zA-Z]+ *[a-zA-Z]*) *\<", dennisov_html)[0]

## Find all of the links when each watch is clicked. Each watch link starts
## with the text "a href=" followed by the subpage, followed by any
## letter, number and "_" symbol combination, followed by a backslash
    global watch_link_urls
    watch_link_urls = findall("a href='" + (dennisov_url_subpage) + "([A-Za-z0-9_]+/)", dennisov_html)  
## Add the main URL to each watch subpage
    watch_link_urls = [str(dennisov_url) + remainder for remainder in watch_link_urls]

## Find all of the model numbers of each watch. Each model starts with the text
## "covername" then any combination of letters, dots and spaces. 
    global watch_names
    watch_names = findall("covername'>([A-Z a-z0-9\.]+)", dennisov_html)

## Get current USD to AUD exchange rate using a known currency website
    currency_converter_url = 'http://www.xe.com/currencyconverter/convert/?From=USD&To=AUD'
    currency_html = urlopen(currency_converter_url).read()
## Replace instances of double quotation marks in the text with singles 
## so that the findall regex code does not get confused 
    currency_html = currency_html.replace('"', "'")
## Find the exchange rate. The exchange rate starts with "uccResultAmount'>"
## and is then followed by any combination of numbers with a decimal place
    exchange_rate = float(findall("uccResultAmount'\>([0-9]+\.[0-9]*)", currency_html)[0])

## Find the price of the models and make into floats. Each model price contains
## numbers followed by the text "USD"
    USD_watch_prices = [float(price) for price in (findall("([0-9]*) usd", dennisov_html))]
    global watch_price
## Convert the USD watch prices to current AUD prices and round to 2 decimals
    watch_price = [round(exchange_rate*price, 2) for price in USD_watch_prices]
## Add the currency to the prices
    global watch_prices
    watch_prices = ["AU $" + str(price) for price in watch_price]

## CREATE A LIST OF MODEL DESCRIPTIONS ACCORDING TO THE TYPE OF WATCH SELECTED:
## > Read each model HTML link in watch_link_urls.
## > Search for the terms inside each URL that start with dib_02 followed by any 
## combination of capital letters, numbers and backslashes.
## > Insert Label and Label grid attributes to each result using a counter to keep track 
## of overall loops in order to create unique names and locations. 
## > Append the results of each loop to a list called watch_model_description_list 
## > Place the results into a dictionary so that the values can be extracted from the 
## lists easily, converted to strings and then executed 
    loop_count = 1
    watch_model_description_list = []
    watch_model_description_grid_list = []
    for num, url in enumerate(watch_link_urls):
        dennisov_model_html = urlopen(url).read()
        dennisov_model_html = dennisov_model_html.replace('"', "'")
        watch_model_description = findall("dib_02'\>([A-Z \/0-9]+)\<", dennisov_model_html)

        for number, category in enumerate(watch_model_description):         
            watch_model_description = 'category_' + str(loop_count) + ' = Label(window, font = ("Helvetica", 5), text = "'+ category +'")'
            watch_model_description_grid = 'category_' + str(loop_count) + '.grid(padx = 0, pady = 0, row = ' + str(number+3) + ', column = '+ str(num) +')'
            watch_model_description_list.append(watch_model_description)
            watch_model_description_grid_list.append(watch_model_description_grid)
            loop_count += 1
    model_option = {'model_{}'.format(i):e for i, e in enumerate(watch_model_description_list)}
    model_grid_option = {'model_grid{}'.format(i):e for i, e in enumerate(watch_model_description_grid_list)}
    model_grid_option_string = '\n'.join(model_grid_option.values())
    model_option_string = '\n'.join(model_option.values())
    exec(model_option_string)
    exec(model_grid_option_string)

## Create the Spinboxes for each watch model
    global spinboxes
    spinboxes = []
    spinbox_grid_list = []
    for number, name in enumerate(watch_names):
        spinboxes.append(Spinbox(window, width = 3, from_= 0, to = 10))
        spinboxes[number].grid(padx = 0, pady = 0, row = 13, column = number)

## Create the prices for each watch model    
    prices = []
    prices_grid_list = []
    for number, price in enumerate(watch_prices):
        prices.append(Label(window, font = ("Helvetica", 10), text = price))
        prices[number].grid(padx = 0, pady = 0, row = 12, column = number)               

## Create the names for each watch model
    names = []
    names_grid_list = []
    for number, name in enumerate(watch_names):
        names.append(Label(window, font = ("Helvetica", 10), text = name))
        names[number].grid(padx = 0, pady = 0, row = 2, column = number)  

## Create a "Create Invoice" button
    invoice_button = Button(window, text = 'Create Invoice', command = create_invoice, width = 20)
    invoice_button.grid(pady = 10, padx = 2, row = 16, columnspan = 9, sticky = "S")

    ## Match each watch name to its image and URL inside a tuple and place each
## tuple inside a list
    watch_list = zip(watch_names, watch_image_urls, watch_prices, watch_link_urls)
## For each watch tuple (matching image, name and URL), assign a watch number
    watch_option = {'watch_{}'.format(i): e for i, e in enumerate(watch_list)}

## Define an action for when the "Create Invoice" button is pushed 

model_quantity_list = []
def create_invoice():
    for spinbox, quantity in enumerate(spinboxes):
        a = float(quantity.get())
        model_quantity_list.append(a)
    model_total_price = [a*b for a,b in zip(model_quantity_list,watch_price)]
## Match each watch with its name, price, URL, image, quantity,
## individual price and price times quantity
    watch_list = zip(watch_names, watch_image_urls, watch_prices, watch_link_urls, model_quantity_list, model_total_price)
## For each watch tuple (matching image, name etc.), assign a watch number
    watch_option = {'watch_{}'.format(i): e for i, e in enumerate(watch_list)}
    for number, each in enumerate(watch_option):
        if watch_option['watch_'+str(number)][4] >= 1:
            print watch_option['watch_'+str(number)]  

## Create dropdown box text
dennisov_dropdown_text = Label(window, text = "Watch type:", bg = 'White', width = 20)

## Create the dropdown box for the Dennisov watch types
dennisov_dropdown_box = Combobox(window, width = 25,
                                  values = dennisov_type_list)

## Create Dennisov type selection button
dennisov_select_button = Button(window, text = 'Select', command = show_models, width = 20)

## Locate elements on grid
dennisov_dropdown_text.grid(pady = 2, padx = 2, row = 1, columnspan = 9, sticky = 'W')
dennisov_dropdown_box.grid(pady = 2, padx = 2, row = 1, columnspan = 9, sticky = 'N')
dennisov_select_button.grid(pady = 2, padx = 2, row = 1, columnspan = 9, sticky = 'E')


dennisov_file.close()

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please don't post so much code. Read and follow the advice here: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move `model_quantity_list = []` into the body of the `create_invoice` function. This will ensure that an empty list is created (discarding the previous selections) anytime the `create_invoice` function is called.

Here is the new function:

```
#model_quantity_list = [] #Not needed
def create_invoice():
    model_quantity_list = [] #Move it here
    for spinbox, quantity in enumerate(spinboxes):
        a = float(quantity.get())
        model_quantity_list.append(a)
    model_total_price = [a*b for a,b in zip(model_quantity_list,watch_price)]
    ## Match each watch with its name, price, URL, image, quantity,
    ## individual price and price times quantity
    watch_list = zip(watch_names, watch_image_urls, watch_prices, watch_link_urls, model_quantity_list, model_total_price)
    ## For each watch tuple (matching image, name etc.), assign a watch number
    watch_option = {'watch_{}'.format(i): e for i, e in enumerate(watch_list)}
    for number, each in enumerate(watch_option):
        if watch_option['watch_'+str(number)][4] >= 1:
            print watch_option['watch_'+str(number)]
```